TAO instance is not connected due to server restarts - how to detect?
I have a CORBA legacy code implemented with ACE/TAO that has some corner cases which my investigation suggests that some connection is no longer valid (tested with ss/netstat).
The interface is described in an IDL file similar to this:
module ReportService
{
     interface ReportTemplateManager {
     ....
     }
}

The interface is found in a singleton class as a member
ReportService::ReportTemplateManager_var    theTemplateManager;

It is initialized in the constructor
theTemplateManager = ReportService::ReportTemplateManager::_narrow(
            theOrb.ior()->resolve(
                        REPGEN_REGUNIT,
                        REPORTTEMPLATEMANAGERNAME,
                        endpointAddress.c_str()));

The problem that I see is the fact that in some cases there is no connection to the endpoint and all the calls seem to block.
Is there a way to check if "theTemplaceManager" is still connected, or a way to force its reconnection once the daemon is restarted?
Any pointer to an example from TAO samples is appreciated.
Thanks!
